# What is the purpose of the diode in this diagram?

Tags: diodes, resistance, ground

If a diode causes resistance then the path of least resistance would always be to ground.  So what is the point of this diode?

[image]

Comment: It's a fly back diode, it is used to protect the transistor from back emf

Comment: Motors are inductive. Inductors seek to prevent rapid changes in current. So when you attempt to switch off a current flowing through an inductor, you generally get a voltage spike of polarity to maintain the current flowing in the same direction as it was before the switch turned off. In this case, the voltage at the collector of Q2 will drop below ground. As it does, the diode becomes forward biased, and clamps the voltage at a reasonable level. So everyone is happy. Without the diode, the voltage dip at Q2 collector would destroy Q2. Potentially.

Comment: So m1 (negative side / cathode?) drains through d1 back to q2 because after power off m1 cathode becomes the high side. But m1 has more impedance naturally than d1 so the remaining current drains to q2 through d1 this draining at a safe level?

Comment: Regardless of the purpose of the diode, that circuit won't work because Q2 can never be cut off.

Comment: You are correct.  That is mentioned as part of this educational arricle the picture is from.

Answer (score 3):

A motor is an inductive load. Inductors “don't like” when current changes suddenly. When that happens, they generate sometimes very high voltages in the reverse direction. It's because when current flows through an inductor, the inductor can store some of its electrical energy, and when the current stops flowing the energy has nowhere to go, so the voltage rises suddenly for a very short time. Such an impulse of high voltage can damage other electrical components in the circuit. The diode lets the voltage spike discharge, because it has polarity opposite to the supply voltage, but blocks the supply voltage from flowing through the diode creating a short circuit. Afrotechmods has a great video on this subject ("Inductive spiking, and how to fix it!").

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We tend to call an outflow of current from a switched OFF inductor "back-EMF". Also your first sentence refers to reversing current instead of current being switched OFF. Please break up your answers into paragraphs so they are easier to read.

Comment: @Sparky256: So what? His answer is fine, not everyone has to use your terms; he described the phenomenon well.  And his first sentence just says "changes", this does not mean reverse (the actual mathematical definition is just v/L = di/dt ; any change makes a difference) .  There is no reason to break it into paragraphs in this case because he is staying on topic.  Not to mention the whole thing is 6 sentences long which is what my high school teachers insisted on anyway for a proper paragraph :P  Why are you nitpicking again???

Comment: @jbord39. I am not nitpicking as these same request were made of me when I posted 'long' answers. A change in context oftens means a new paragraph. It is simply easier to read, based on words per line. These were suggestions to the OP, not demands.